# How to fetch the http status code when the response type defined is string instead of Respone

Tags: java, api, rest, automation, rest-assured

int statusCode = res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();[Please refer for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbplZ.png)

Is there any way to cast string to Response to use the predefined method getStatusCode() else any other way to fetch the status code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In your example you assert that your code would be `200` so your won't pass further if you have any different code..

Comment: That's adding assertion you are talking about, but I need to fetch the HTTP response status code and I am unable to do so using predefined method getStatusCode() as I have defined response(res) to be string @AlexeyR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have both `Response` and `String`, for example.

```
Response response = given().patch();
int statusCode = response.statusCode();

String res = response.asString();
```